# How can I get my spinner to fill with database data?

Tags: android

I'm having a lot of problems trying to get my spinner to fill with data after my application loads.  I'm just messing around and made a database for vehicles. So I'm trying to get a spinner to load the database data into it.  This is the code I use in a method to attempt to do so, but my spinner is never loaded with my database data.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = database.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT vehicle_make, vehicle_model, vehicle_year FROM vehicles;", null);
vehicleProfileSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.vehicleProfileSpinner); 
startManagingCursor(cursor);

String[] columns = {"vehicle_year", "vehicle_make", "vehicle_model"};
int[] theView = {R.id.vehicleProfileSpinner};
SimpleCursorAdapter vpsAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, cursor, columns, theView);
vpsAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.main);
vehicleProfileSpinner.setAdapter(vpsAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case instead of using Simplecursoradapter, I have created array from cursor entries and created ArrayAdapter and set it to list. It worked perfect. Somehow Simplecursor adapter looks for ID field and causing issue,so I ignored it and used Arrayadapter. I will try to update this post with example I posted for other question.

Answer (score 0):

One thing is all you need SimpleCusorAdapter.